# How Xcode7.2.1 support lua syntax highlight?

Tags: xcode, lua

This tool seems not work now https://github.com/breinhart/Lua-In-Xcode 
Is there a way to support lua syntax highlight in Xcode7.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

I used that same [github project](https://github.com/breinhart/Lua-In-Xcode).

The fix is to open a command prompt and run this:

```
rm -f /private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.DeveloperTools/*/Xcode/PlugInCache*.xcplugincache
```

Then you should see it under `Editor->Syntax Coloring->Lua`.

Source: https://github.com/breinhart/Lua-In-Xcode/issues/4

**EDIT**: I've since added a fix to support Xcode 7, and also beta verisons (e.g. Xcode 8 beta) with the `--beta` flag. See: https://github.com/mrhappyasthma/Lua-In-Xcode. A pull request has been created, but it seems the original author does not actively maintain the pull requests.

Comment: Thank you for this update. Do you know how to make Xcode recognise .lua files automatically (i.e. without the need for selecting it via the menu)? Or should it do that already?

Comment: It doesn't do that, and unfortunately it cannot be done (as far as I can tell). Lots of trial-and-error and googling has turned up nothing useful. If you ever discover it, let me know how!